# CriteriaQuery search in jsonb postgres column

Tags: java, postgresql, jsonb, hibernate-criteria

I have table with jsonb column "opinion_cells", example data:

```
[{"isFinalOpinion": false, "assignedPersonId": null, "organizationUnitId": 2}, 
{"isFinalOpinion": false, "assignedPersonId": 12, "organizationUnitId": 3}]
```

I need to select records by "assignedPersonId" using criteria query.

I tried to write expression:

```
Expression<String> opinionCellAssignedPerson = criteriaBuilder.function(
      "json_extract_path_text",
      String.class,
      internalLetterRoot.get(InternalLetter_.OPINION_CELLS),
      criteriaBuilder.literal("assignedPersonId")
  );
```

but in returns nothing, because of [] content is treated as an array. When I remove [] from column content then it works.

I also tried

```
Expression<String> opinionCellArrayToJson = criteriaBuilder.function(
      "json_array_elements",
      String.class,
      internalLetterRoot.get(InternalLetter_.OPINION_CELLS)
  );
```

and then:

Expression opinionCellAssignedPerson = criteriaBuilder.function(
"json_extract_path_text",
String.class,
opinionCellArrayToJson ,
criteriaBuilder.literal("assignedPersonId")
);

but it returns:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of OR must not return a set
```

My question is: It is possible using criteria query?